# Why is my CSS breaking?

Tags: css, html

I have been looking at my code for long time now and I still fail to see why this is breaking.  Other pages in the same folder have the EXACT same code for the navbar however on this one it breaks.

www.orikina.com/HDD/dev/classes.php    //This one is broken

www.orikina.com/HDD/dev/index.php       //This one is not.

Thanks, Tim

Comment: The HTML markup is different in both pages. How do you expect this to work?

Comment: I dont understand. @Thilak Rao

Comment: I think @JonathandeM. is asking you to copy paste the relevant code rather than just linking to your sites.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: [7 Errors, 4 warning(s)](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.orikina.com%2FHDD%2Fdev%2Fclasses.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the html source line 23:

> `<li<a href="index.php">Home</a></li>`

Comment: less a "<" ,see that?

Comment: I need to wait 5min to have you as the answer, Thank you.   I feel stupid now.

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap.js file is not loaded on broken page 
you forgot

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just loaded it on, its for the JS plugins, it seems like a CSS problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a markup problem here :

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li<a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="classes.php">Classes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">User Area</a></li>
    </ul>
...
```

See the line

```
<li<a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
```